# Angular 2 material using flex layout module

Tags: angular, flexbox

I am building an Angular 2 application and decided to use Angular 2 material module. However the flex layout module is not working : https://github.com/angular/flex-layout.

So I have created a new project using the latest version of angular-cli (beta 24) and added flex layout following these steps: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Integration-with-Angular-CLI but no difference. Does anyone used these or have an idea how to make it work ?

in my app.module.ts

```
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    .........
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    MaterialModule.forRoot(),
    FlexLayoutModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

**UPDATE**

Sorry for improper question. After reading Angular's blog I saw that flex-layout module works with Angular 2.4.x but my angular-cli generates Angular 2.3.1 project. This is my package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "demo2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.24",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.0.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3"
  }
}
```

I have tried to update manually the package.json file to :

```
{
  "name": "demo2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.2",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "zone": "^0.3.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-cli": "^1.0.0-beta.24",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.0.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.10"
  }
}
```

Now when I am trying to install @angular/flex-layout it says :

```
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.4.1
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.4.1
├── @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.1 
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.2
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@0.7.4

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@2.2.3 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.2.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@2.2.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.2.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@~2.2.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@~2.2.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.1 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.1 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.6.21 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@1.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/compiler-cli@^2.3.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN tslint-loader@2.1.5 requires a peer of tslint@^3.0.0 but none was installed.
```

Why @angular/flex-layout requires @angular/core older that 2.4 if it only works on versions greater than 2.4 ?

**SOLUTION**

After many unsuccessful attempt I have decided to build @angular/flex-layout on my own. So what I have done was to follow these steps :

```
Getting your environment set up

Make sure you have node installed with a version at least 5.5.0.
Run npm install -g gulp to install gulp.
Run npm install -g yarn to install yarn.
Fork the angular/flex-layout repo.
Clone your fork. Recommendation: name your git remotes upstream for angular/flex-layout and <your-username> for your fork. Also see the team git shortcuts.
From the root of the project, run yarn install.


Building the library

To build the library in dev mode, run gulp build:lib.
To build the library in release mode, run gulp build:release
```

- copy flex-layout folder inside node_modules/@angular
- make the proper modifications inside app.module.ts to import the FlexLayoutModule

Comment: Thank you for feedback. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

That is better.  I can see that you are getting unmet peer dependencies.  This will stop things from working right away.  The warnings are not the first stoppers, but the @angular/common@2.4.1 will be.  If I look at your output,

```
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.4.1
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.4.1
├── @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.1 
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.2
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@0.7.4
```

These tell me main things are missing.  I believe your one problem now is that you have a collection of things in this project that are causing you trouble. You are missing the rxjs and zone.js with these errors.  These need the proper versions installed in the project as well.

Looking at the output, your angular-cli wants angular compiler 2.2.3.

```
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@2.2.3 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.2.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@2.2.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.2.3 but none was installed.
```

Flex layout 2.0.0-beta.1 also wants angular compiler 2.2.3

```
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@~2.2.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@~2.2.3 but none was installed.
```

This is good, they both want the same angular.  I would therefore go back and do a clean install of your angular-cli.  Then either modify the package.json, or use npm install, and add the flex-layout 2.0.0-beta.1.  This will clean up the main errors, and should get you close to the Flex being installed.  You still need to add it to a page and show what is not working from a rendering point of view.

One thing to watch out for, as you are using betas and quick start tools and libraries, is inconsistency between dependencies.  The flex beta will be a work in progress, and will likely lag behind the actual Angular 2 release as they have to keep incorporating the changes like everyone else.